# Are 2 cpu machines better for single tasks or multiple tasks

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

I realize that there may not be a hard and fast rule but it seems 2 CPU machines will provide greater performance improvement when running multiple tasks as opposed to just running one task.  Is this true in a Windows environment? Would a different OS make a difference?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing exactly (and I mean exactly) what the “tasks” are – and especially what definition of a “task” are you using. Normally we’d talk about threads, not tasks! And modern OSes have lots of their own threads, even in the kernel, so even if you’re running just a single-threaded lone application in userspace (think PID 1 on Unix), if that single thread does a lot of I/O interspersed with computations, more than 1 CPU thread will be busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the old days CPU's were what we today would call "single core" and if you had a program use 100% CPU there was nothing left for anything else, including the taskbar you tried to get up with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Two CPU systems (I had a dual Pentium III system at one time) fixed this as the other CPU was usually not 100% busy so it could handle the taskmanager even with the rogue program running at full speed.

Today this has moved inside the single CPU as multiple cores.  So having more cores than rogue programs running at the same time is a good thing.  For most users this is a dual core system but prices are falling and an eight core AMD CPU can be bought for under $100. I believe it is close to impossible to find a singe core CPU these days.

Comment: Note that some programs can use more than one core ("multi-threaded") but it is hard to do all the time (unless you have lot of repetitive similar work, like video rendering or graphics-intensive games).